# how to make a .py file to a model

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

draw.py

```
from PIL import Image
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('file')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output')
parser.add_argument('--width', type = int, default = 80)
parser.add_argument('--height', type = int, default = 80)

args = parser.parse_args()

IMG = args.file
WIDTH = args.width
HEIGHT = args.height
OUTPUT = args.output

ascii_char = list("$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'. ")

def get_char(r,b,g,alpha = 256):
    if alpha == 0:
        return ' '
    length = len(ascii_char)
    gray = int(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)

    unit = (256.0 + 1)/length
    return ascii_char[int(gray/unit)]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    im = Image.open(IMG)
    im = im.resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT), Image.NEAREST)

    txt = ""

    for i in range(HEIGHT):
        for j in range(WIDTH):
            txt += get_char(*im.getpixel((j,i)))
        txt += '\n'

    print txt

    if OUTPUT:
        with open(OUTPUT,'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)
    else:
        with open("output.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)
```

using  a the code above,

> python draw.py image.png

I can get a ascii image like this:

[image]

Now I want to make it a model, so I can import it, then I make an ascii image with image.jpg(or bmp, png....) in the same path, using just a function, which can print it out, and write it in a txt file

Answer (score 1):

draw.py

```
from PIL import Image

ASCII_CHAR = list("$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'. ")

def get_char(r,b,g,alpha = 256):
    if alpha == 0:
        return ' '
    length = len(ASCII_CHAR)
    gray = int(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)

    unit = (256.0 + 1)/length
    return ASCII_CHAR[int(gray / unit)]

def get_ascii_image(im, width, height):
    if isinstance(im, basestring):
        im = Image.open(im)
        im = im.resize((width, height), Image.NEAREST)

    txt = ""
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            txt += get_char(*im.getpixel((j, i)))
        txt += '\n'
    return txt


def save(txt, output):
    if output:
        with open(output, 'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)
    else:
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('file')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output')
    parser.add_argument('--width', type=int, default=80)
    parser.add_argument('--height', type=int, default=80)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    IMG = args.file
    WIDTH = args.width
    HEIGHT = args.height
    OUTPUT = args.output

    txt = get_ascii_image(IMG, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    print txt

    save(txt, OUTPUT)
```

other_python_file.py

```
import draw

txt = draw.get_ascii_image("PATH", width=80, height=80)
draw.save(txt, "DESTINATION_PATH")
```

Comment: txt = draw.get_ascii_image("myPATH"),                                                       it says"global name 'WIDTH' is not defined"